# Store users choice of CSS-style with local storage (How?)

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

The user can choose between 4 different themes (4 different CSS-files) by clicking links. The users choice should be saved (and somehow selected by being bold for example) in local storage and the chosen CSS-style should then be loaded when the user opens up the webpage. The choice should be stored for at least a week.

I am completely new to local storage so I am uncertain of how I should approach this. As far as I understand, `localStorage.setItem`, `localStorage.getItem` and `onChange()` should be included somewhere and somehow.
All code should be in javascript, and no jQuery.
**HTML**

```js
    function changeCSS(sheet) {
       document.getElementById('stylesheet_1').setAttribute('href', sheet);
    }
    
    var stylesheets = document.getElementsByClassName("left_sub8");
    
    stylesheets[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
       changeCSS('inlamning7_utseende1.css');
    });
    stylesheets[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
       changeCSS('inlamning7_utseende2.css');
    });
    stylesheets[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
       changeCSS('inlamning7_utseende3.css');
    });
    stylesheets[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
       changeCSS('inlamning7_utseende4.css');
    });
```

```html
    <a class="left_top">Personligt utseende</a><br>
                <div class="left_submenu_8" style="display: none;">
                <a id="style_1" class="left_sub8" value="inlamning7_utseende1">Default</a><br>
                <a id="style_2" class="left_sub8" value="inlamning7_utseende2">Dark</a><br>
                <a id="style_3" class="left_sub8" value="inlamning7_utseende3">Pastell</a><br>
                <a id="style_4" class="left_sub8" value="inlamning7_utseende4">Gray</a><br>
```

Any suggestions of how the code would look like to make things work? My main problem is to create code that makes the local storage work, so that´s the top-priority. But have the chosen CSS-file being selected through javascript would be great as well.

Comment: Why not just reorganize this, adding only a class to body tag according to users choice and store this variable value as a cookie?

Comment: I have no experience with cookies either, so that is not making me any wiser...

Comment: So, instead of making "roulette" with switching over files, research how to make it in a much cleaner way with managing body classes. There is one plugin jQuery Cookies which will make it even easier. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem! Thought this might be useful to other than just me so here it is:

**Javascript**

```
function changeCSS(sheet) { 
     document.getElementById('active_stylesheet').setAttribute('href', sheet);
     localStorage.setItem('sheet', sheet);
}

var stylesheets = document.getElementsByClassName("left_sub8");

stylesheets[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
     changeCSS('inlamning7_utseende1.css');
});
stylesheets[1].addEventListener("click", function(){
     changeCSS('inlamning7_utseende2.css');
});
stylesheets[2].addEventListener("click", function(){
     changeCSS('inlamning7_utseende3.css');
});
stylesheets[3].addEventListener("click", function(){
     changeCSS('inlamning7_utseende4.css');
});

window.onload=function() {
     document.getElementById('active_stylesheet').setAttribute("href", localStorage.getItem("sheet"));
};
```

*Note 1: I did not change the html-code so that is the same as in the question above*

*Note 2: There is another problem now, which is unless the user chooses a theme, no css-document is loaded at all. This is not good, so a css-file needs be loaded by default if no theme is selected by the user. This remains to be solved.*

Comment: document.getElementById('active_stylesheet').setAttribute("href", localStorage.getItem("sheet")?localStorage.getItem("sheet"):"yourdefault.css");

Comment: @Tim `localStorage.getItem("sheet"):"yourdefault.css");` does not work (if you suggested to have that instead of `document.getElementById('active_stylesheet').setAttribute("href", localStorage.getItem("sheet")`)

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('active_stylesheet').setAttribute("href", localStorage.getItem("sheet")?localStorage.getItem("sheet"):"yourdefault.css");` instead of `document.getElementById('active_stylesheet').setAttribute("href", localStorage.getItem("sheet"));`

Comment: @Tim How would you write this in the long way? I have not used your format much so I want to make sure I understand it :). Also, do you know how I can remove the users choice of theme? I clicked to see if the local storage worked and now a choice is saved (so now it´s difficult to see if the default code works). WouId a browser reset do the trick? I really want to try your code.

Comment: @Tim I reset my browser and tried your code and now it has a default css and everything seems to be working now. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just save the `sheet` in your `changeCSS()`:

```
localStorage.setItem('sheet', sheet);
```

And then apply it on pageload. So something like

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    changeCSS(localStorage.getItem('sheet'));
});
```

Checkout the documentation for the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

Comment: How can I specify for how long I want the information to be stored? Since the users choice should be stored for at least a week.

Comment: The localStorage is never erased automatically. But it will be deleted on browser reset.

Comment: Ok then! I tried to apply your suggestion, but unfortunately it´s not working

Comment: I cannot precise as to _why_ your suggestion is not working. However I managed to solve it earlier today, but now I have another problem: if the users have not selected a theme, no css-file is loaded at all (which is not good), so a default css is needed.

Comment: Separate your css into 2 files, layout.css and colors.css (that is light.css, dark.css and so on). Load layout.css always. If ternary operator is difficult use something like this: `var theme=localStorage.getItem('sheet'); if(!theme) theme='default'; document.getElementById('active_stylesheet').setAttribute("href", theme);`

Comment: @Isus try to explain *what* is not working. What errors do you get, what is your behavior. *May* edit your questions. *May* provide non-working jsbin or git repo.

Comment: @Lux please see my own answer down below. I managed to make the local storage work (so that the users choice of theme is saved and loaded the next time he/she visits the webpage). But now, if the user do not choose any theme, no css-file is loaded at all, which is not good. Therefore, a css-file needs to be made default **IF** the user have not chosen a theme. Then, to see if the default works I need to do a browser reset or remove the local storage temporarily. Because as it is now, there is a theme saved in the local storage. I hope I have explained better now.